# What is OpenCV HighGUI namespace?

Tags: opencv, namespaces

If I do not use any namespace my code works just fine, but when I try using a method with namespace like this:

`cv::nameOfMethodInHighGUI()`

the compiler tells me that `cv` has no member method called like that.

So I've thought that `highgui.h` and `cv.h` have different namespaces, am I right?

Can anybody please tell what namespace I should use to call methods from the header file `highgui.h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All opencv functions envolve in the namespace cv !

So to display an image you can use cv::imshow (on opencv >2)

Comment: it's what I thought, but if I call method like this:

cv::cvShowImage( imagePath.c_str(), frame ); I get this compiler error:

’cvShowImage’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Comment: That's because it is now `cv::imshow()` as explained in the documentation (for 2.3): http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow

Comment: Yes, but if you use a namespace the "cv" prefix of fuctions disapear ! And some functions are renamed.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing `highgui.h` I have the following idea:
Maybe you have accidentally mixed the old-fashioned and the new OpenCV2 include headers (as both are shipped with OpenCV2+ libraries).

I recommend only using

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

They have every function in the `cv` namespace.